# Error : Warning message:In system(cmd) : 'make' not found

Tags: c++, r

I am working with R and C++. I am trying to include C++ in R , I have the following code:

```
install.packages('inline')
install.packages('Rcpp')
install.packages('rstan')
library('inline')
library('Rcpp')
library('rstan')

### # start with pure C/C++ function and assign the source code to
### #  a variable which we call here includesrc
includesrc <- '
int fibonacci(const int x){
  if (x == 0) return(0);
  if (x == 1) return(1);
  return fibonacci(x-1) + fibonacci(x-2);
}'

### # define the body of the C/C++ program
fibCppBody <- '
int x = Rcpp::as<int>(xs);
return Rcpp::wrap( fibonacci(x) );'

### # pass the above C/C++ function as an argument
### # to cxxfunction()
fibRcpp <- inline::cxxfunction(sig = signature(xs = "int"),
                               plugin = "Rcpp",
                               incl = includesrc,
                               body = fibCppBody)

sapply(1:10, fibRcpp, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
```

I ran this code which is supposed to include C++ code in R function , it is supposed to run (it is an example from [here](https://charlotte-ngs.github.io/RStudioDevCpp/RStudioDevCppPost.html) but it's not working for me.

And I got this error:

```
Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created!
Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
  Warning message:In system(cmd) : 'make' not found
```

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Install `make`.  See [all these earlier questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+make+not+found).

Comment: It seems that my R version doesn't support "make", is there a way to look for a "make" version for my R version or it may be better to import my C++ code?

Comment: `make` is not an R thing. It's a separate program that needs to be installed on your computer. Try looking at the answers to those other questions in a bit more detail. Currently it's unclear what operating system you are even using.

Comment: I am using Windows, so I gotta install make for Windows

Comment: I installed Make from https://cygwin.com/install.html but I 'm still having the error : Warning message:In system(cmd) : 'make' not found

Comment: You _really_ need to read up on "installing Rtools for Windows" within the _existing R documentation_.